# Button class in href tag

Tags: html

When a user clicks the button it has a `href` to another html page in the same folder as the current page to open.

But I get a 404 error, however it works for external websites.

This is the code:

```
<a class="btn btn-sample btn-lg" href="next.html">next page</a>
```

How could I correct this, thanks

Comment: In your browsers F12 Network Inspector look for the request to next.html - that will show you the full (clickable) URL the page should reside at.

Comment: Got it working, issue was that as I'm using a Tornado server I had to use the handler name for the actual html page I was referencing to.

Answer (score 2):

use current directory `href="./whatever"`

```
<a class="btn btn-sample btn-lg" href="./next.html">next page</a>
```

Comment: Try to change manually the url in the browser, only the last section, changing current page for next.html. If it gives you a 404, then the problem is not in the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button"> 

   <a class=" *** " href="helloworld.html"/>

   link name </a>

 </button>  // close tag /button
```